# Databinding of ObservableCollection to TextBoxes in Tab

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I started writing an application and I am facing trouble with the databinding of an observablecollection, because I am not very familiar with WPF an Binding. Further the different method of binding like object binding, xaml binding are confusing me.

The idea is to retrieve data from a SQL statement and add them to a observablecollection. Afterwards textboxes/comboboxes which are located in a tab in the mainwindows should be updated with this data.

I have a SQL Class which is retrieving the data from a sqlserver and populating the observablecollection. The following code is working at the moment:

```
    Imports System.Data.Sql
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.Xml.Linq
    Public Class SQLQueries    
    Public Sub GetPersonData(ByVal HRID_TextBox_OnB As String)
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.AppConnString.ToString) 'connectionstring is retrieved from app settings
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(QPersonDataQuery & "and person.personnelnumber = @DBG_HRID", con)        
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBG_HRID", HRID_TextBox_OnB)        
            Dim PersonData As New ObservableCollection(Of String)                PersonData.Clear()
            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If (reader.HasRows) Then
                    While (reader.Read())
                        For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                            PersonData.Add(i)
                        Next i
                    End While
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Better call Saul!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf + ex.Message)
            Finally
                If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Close()
            End Try
            con.Dispose()
         End Sub
End Class
```

My XAML is looking like this at the moment:

```
        <Window x:Class="MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"


            Title="FAT Client Primary Access" Height="609" Width="811" Background="White">
            <Grid>
                <Menu IsMainMenu="True" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White">
                    <MenuItem Header="_File">
                        <MenuItem Header="_Close" Click="CloseApp_Click"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Database">
                        <MenuItem Header="_Check Connection" Click="CheckConnection_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_Change Connection String" Click="ChangeConnection_Click"/>
                    </MenuItem>

                </Menu>
                <TabControl Height="544" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,26,0,0" Name="TabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="789" Background="White">
                    <TabItem Header="Onboarding" Name="TabItem1" Background="White">
                        <Grid Background="White" Width="797" Height="524">
                            <Label Content="HRID" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,24,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,24,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" />
                            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="182,23,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
                            <TextBox Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,104,0,0" Name="TextBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" />
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="other Trigger" Name="TabItem2" Background="White">
                        <Grid Background="White" />
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
        </Window>
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to bind the first value in my observablecollection to textbox2. I tried and read a lot but this was more confusing then helping out.

Do I need a separate Class to bind the observablecollection to the textboxes?

I would appreciate it if could give a me small hint.

Thanks in advance. And also Hello everybody.

Comment: What is the DataContext of your Window?

Comment: Nothing. I didn't set a datacontext. That it somehow my problem. I saw some sample codes from other guys around here. I need to know which steps I have to perform to establish such a data context.

Comment: Databinding goes to the Grid's DataContext. More [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF). Then you bind child objects inside here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding [2].Name}" />
```

This binding path will show Name property of 3rd element of your ObservableCollection.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding [0].Name}" />
```

So, this will show Name of first element of your collection.

But how Textbox will know what is the collection to use ? For that you have to set DataContext either at root level, or at your TextBox level. This root can be anywhere above your TextBox. DataContext set at this root will be visible within all children of this root only.

Your data can be complex like Country>States>City.For example, you can set  DataContext to Country at root level, and some child elements can then use States, while some can use City etc.

So, set DataContext like this :

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Class MainWindow
    Public Property InvoiceCollection As New ObservableCollection(Of Invoice) 
    Public Sub New()  
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()  
        ' Fill your InvoiceCollection.
        ...
        ...        
        Me.DataContext = InvoiceCollection
    End Sub     
End Class
```

Then you can show TotalPrice of first Invoice item like :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding [0].TotalPrice}" />
```

You can even set DataContext of TextBox2 like :

```
TextBox2.DataContext = InvoiceCollection[0]
```

then databinding will look like :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" />
```

You can even set DataContext of TextBox2 like :

```
TextBox2.DataContext = InvoiceCollection
```

then databinding will look like :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding [0].TotalPrice}" />
```

Few important links :

1. [DataBinding in 7 part series](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html)
2. [Property path syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms742451(v=vs.100).aspx)